# Flink: RowRowConverter seems to fail for nested DataTypes

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-sql

I am trying to load a complex JSON file (multiple different data types, nested objects/arrays etc) from my local, read them in as a source using the [Table API File System Connector](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/table/filesystem/), [convert](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/dev/table/data_stream_api/#examples-for-todatastream) them into DataStream, and then do some action afterwards (not shown here for brevity).

The conversion gives me a DataStream of type `DataStream[Row]`, which I need to convert to `DataStream[RowData]` (for sink purposes, won't go into details here). Thankfully, there's a [RowRowConverter](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/api/java/org/apache/flink/table/data/conversion/RowRowConverter.html) utility that helps to do this mapping. It works when I tried a completely flat JSON, but when I introduced Arrays and Maps within the JSON, it no longer works.

Here is the exception that was thrown - a null pointer exception:

```
    at org.apache.flink.table.data.conversion.ArrayObjectArrayConverter.allocateWriter(ArrayObjectArrayConverter.java:140)
    at org.apache.flink.table.data.conversion.ArrayObjectArrayConverter.toBinaryArrayData(ArrayObjectArrayConverter.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.table.data.conversion.ArrayObjectArrayConverter.toInternal(ArrayObjectArrayConverter.java:93)
    at org.apache.flink.table.data.conversion.ArrayObjectArrayConverter.toInternal(ArrayObjectArrayConverter.java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.table.data.conversion.DataStructureConverter.toInternalOrNull(DataStructureConverter.java:61)
    at org.apache.flink.table.data.conversion.RowRowConverter.toInternal(RowRowConverter.java:75)
    at flink.ReadJsonNestedData$.$anonfun$main$2(ReadJsonNestedData.scala:48)
```

Interestingly, when I setup my breakpoints and debugger this is what I discovered: `RowRowConverter::toInternal`, the first time it was called works, will go all the way down to `ArrayObjectArrayConverter::allocateWriter()`

[image]

However, for some strange reason, `RowRowConverter::toInternal` runs twice, and if I continue stepping through eventually it will come back here, which is where the null pointer exception happens.

[image]

Example of the JSON (simplified with only a single nested for brevity). I placed it in my `/src/main/resources` folder

```json
{"discount":[670237.997082,634079.372133,303534.821218]}
```

```scala
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.api.DataTypes
import org.apache.flink.table.api.bridge.java.StreamTableEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.table.data.conversion.RowRowConverter
import org.apache.flink.table.types.FieldsDataType
import org.apache.flink.table.types.logical.RowType

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

object ReadJsonNestedData {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // setup
    val jsonResource = getClass.getResource("/NESTED.json")
    val jsonFilePath = jsonResource.getPath
    val tableName = "orders"
    val readJSONTable =
      s"""
         | CREATE TABLE $tableName (
         |  `discount` ARRAY<DECIMAL(12, 6)>
         | )WITH (
         |    'connector' = 'filesystem',
         |    'path' = '$jsonFilePath',
         |    'format' = 'json'
         |)""".stripMargin

    val colFields = Array(
      "discount"
    )

    val defaultDataTypes = Array(
      DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.DECIMAL(12, 6))
    )

    val rowType = RowType.of(defaultDataTypes.map(_.getLogicalType), colFields)
    val defaultDataTypesAsList = defaultDataTypes.toList.asJava
    val dataType = new FieldsDataType(rowType, defaultDataTypesAsList)
    val rowConverter = RowRowConverter.create(dataType)

    // Job
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()
    val tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
    tableEnv.executeSql(readJSONTable)
    val ordersTable = tableEnv.from(tableName)
    val dataStream = tableEnv
      .toDataStream(ordersTable)
      .map(row => rowConverter.toInternal(row))

    dataStream.print()
    env.execute()
  }

}
```

I would hence like to know:

1. Why `RowRowConverter` is not working and how I can remedy it
2. Why `RowRowConverter::toInternal` is running twice for the same `Row` .. which may be the cause of that `NullPointerException`
3. If my method of instantiating and using the `RowRowConverter` is correct based on my code above.

Thank you!

Environment:

- IntelliJ 2021.3.2 (Ultimate)
- AdoptOpenJDK `1.8`
- Scala: `2.12.15`
- Flink: `1.13.5`
- Flink Libraries Used (for this example):

  - `flink-table-api-java-bridge`
  - `flink-table-planner-blink`
  - `flink-clients`
  - `flink-json`

Answer (score 2):

The first call of `RowRowConverter::toInternal` is an internal implementation for making a deep copy of the StreamRecord emitted by table source, which is independent from the converter in your map function. The reason of the NPE is that the `RowRowConverter` in the map function is not initialized by calling `RowRowConverter::open`. You can use `RichMapFunction` instead to invoke the `RowRowConverter::open` in `RichMapFunction::open`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to @renqs for the answer.

Here is the code, if anyone is interested.

```
class ConvertRowToRowDataMapFunction(fieldsDataType: FieldsDataType)
    extends RichMapFunction[Row, RowData] {
  private final val rowRowConverter = RowRowConverter.create(fieldsDataType)

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    super.open(parameters)
    rowRowConverter.open(this.getClass.getClassLoader)
  }

  override def map(row: Row): RowData =
    this.rowRowConverter.toInternal(row)
}

// at main function
// ... continue from previous
val dataStream = tableEnv
      .toDataStream(personsTable)
      .map(new ConvertRowToRowDataMapFunction(dataType))
```